# Error 2200: Copy Activity - Partitioned Parquet Column Not Found

Tags: copy, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, parquet, sqlbulkcopy

Things I've tried:

I have checked the pipeline's JSON and none of the columns have a space in them.

I added in the "physicalType: "UTF8"" to the JSON as it was missing beforehand.

The schemas for the source dataset, sink dataset, and copy activity are all imported schemas - none of them are hardcoded.

I've tried unchecking and re-checking the "Enable Partition Discovery" on the Source dataset in the Copy Activity

Other things to note: the source is a blob container. The sink is a table in Azure SQL.

IMAGE 1: Error
https://ibb.co/qjQpZCW

IMAGE 2: Original Copy Activity Mapping
https://ibb.co/6YgBKzx

IMAGE 3: Updated Copy Activity Mapping after editing the JSON
https://ibb.co/P13KwVb

IMAGE 4: Added physicalType to JSON
https://ibb.co/SXpXM1p

IMAGE 5: Source File Structure
https://ibb.co/G2QV9Dc

I'm sure it's simple, but I've run into this error before and ended up dropping that column. But for this, I'd love to be able to keep the time_period column in this Copy Activity.

Here is the error code text:
Error code: 2200
Failure type: User configuration issue
Details: ErrorCode=ParquetColumnNotFound,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column time_period does not exist in Parquet file.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.ParquetTransferPlugin,'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I got more details of your question from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/582075/error-2200-copy-activity-partitioned-parquet-colum.html)

Issue is with path of files. I would recommend you to use **File path type** as **List of files** as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

List of files option Point to a text file that lists each file (relative path to the path configured in the dataset) that you want to copy.

You have to prepare text file with path of all files.

In **Path of file list** you have to provide path of text file, which contains list of files.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I no longer have an error, but the entire partition column is NULL in the Azure SQL DB. Any ideas?